# Making one http request with Netty

Tags: java, http, netty

In all of the [http examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http) for Netty the client is making just one request and then closes all resources.

In order to make the request two new thread pulls are created:

```
ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(
              new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
```

And I'm wondering if this is necessary for just one request, especially when the requests in the examples are synchronized, isn't there a simpler way to make that just one request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need Netty for just one request? There are simpler ways to do that. Using of Netty implies working with heavy load.

Comment: I'm new to Netty and going over the examples for http and it just seemed strange to me the way it's done in there. I agree that there are simpler ways than Netty for that, so why haven't they used one there instead? Or alternatively, why haven't they showed a few clients sharing the *NioClientSocketChannelFactory*? I was basically just curious.

Comment: Because requests are not handled synchronously in Netty. Requests are sent in one thread, responses are handled in another one.

Comment: So why didn't they show how to reuse the *NioClientSocketChannelFactory* instance in their examples? That would make more sense. Anyway, I get your point. Thanks.